# How to identify a new tab is opened by user clicked link in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How to identify a new tab is opened by user clicked link in Chrome extension?

Usually we could create a new tab in chrome by these way:

1. click a hyperlink in a exsiting tab;
2. input a new url in the omnibox and press Alt-key to open a new tab;
3. click the New Tab button of Chrome;

in the extension api:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((_t) => {
    chrome.tabs.get(_t.openerTabId, function(_tParent) {
            console.log('parent tab : ', _tParent.url, _tParent.pendingUrl);
    });
    console.log('created tab : ', _t.id, _t.openerTabId, _t.pendingUrl, _t.url);
});
```

After testing the above three ways separately, I found that the Chrome could not distinguish between ways 1, 2, 3.

Cause even I tried the way 2 & 3, the results still show the Parent tab id,
In other words, even a new tab is created by clicking the New Tab Button of Chrome, the new tab still contains the "tab.openerTabId".

the Console:

```
create :::  2602 662 chrome://newtab/ 
parent :  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71072377/edit undefined
```

Comment: chrome.tabs.onCreated is the correct event but the URL may be assigned later, which you can observe in chrome.tabs.onUpdated.

Comment: Thank you, Could you tell more detail about that ? I need to identify the new tab is opened by clicking  <a herf="xxx" ></a> in the parent page, not the NewTabButton of Chrome or Ctrl + T action.

Comment: All right, I'll add the MCVE to the question later :)

Comment: Added MCVE , thank you :)

Comment: Apparently there's no API for this so you'll have to use a `click` event in the content script and then check if the tab with this openerTabId opened within 100ms and also check the url.

Comment: Thank you. so regretful, I remember Chrome provide this function earlier : after enable a function in the chrome://flags , when the user click a hyperlink in a tab ungrouped, the new tab will group automatically with its parent tab and itselft.